# i have csv file and how to create new file for every same first five digit phone number and file name also shoud be first 5 digit

Tags: perl, csv

I have csv file like below.

```
Service Area Code   Phone Numbers   Preferences      
17  9861511646  0   D   2 
17  9861310397  0   D   2 
13  9827035035  0   A   2 
13  9827304969  0   D   2 
13  9827355786  0   A   2 
13  9827702373  0   A   2 
17  9861424414  0   D   2 
13  9827702806  0   A   2
23  9832380279  0   D   2 
13  9827231370  0   D   2 
13  9827163453  0   D   2
```

and i want to create new file according to first 4 digit like 9861.csv, 9827.csv etc

and data should be like this in 9861.csv:

```
Service Area Code   Phone Numbers   Preferences
17  9861511646  0   D   2
17  9861310397  0   D   2
17  9861424414  0   D   2
```

in 9827.csv data:

```
Service Area Code   Phone Numbers   Preferences
13  9827035035  0   A   2
13  9827304969  0   D   2
13  9827355786  0   A   2
13  9827702373  0   A   2
13  9827702806  0   A   2
13  9827231370  0   D   2
13  9827163453  0   D   2
```

here my code

```
my $file = "mycsvfile.csv";

open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my $line = <$data>) {
        my @fields = split "," , $line;
        my $first_four = substr ($fields[1],  -10,  4,);

        open $line{$first_four}, '>', "$first_four.csv";

        print  { $line{$first_four} } $line;
        close OUT;
}
```

Comment: why do you split your lines with `,` comma? i cant see a comma there. You need to split it with `' '` space :D. Oh, and why do you `close OUT` ?? there is no filehandle called `OUT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you use `$first_five` instead of `$first_four`...

```
my $file = "mycsvfile.csv";

open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my $line = <$data>) {

        my @fields = split "," , $line;
        my $first_four = substr($fields[1],  0,  4);

        open my $fh, '>>', "$first_four.csv" or die $!;

        print  {$fh} $line;
        close $fh;
}
close $data;
```

Comment: one more thing how can i add same header in each file.

Comment: You can check if each result file exists (using `-e`) before opening it. If there is no such file -- create it and print header.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Text::CSV` it will take some of the hassle (like the header line) from you.